# (swipeup) isn't triggering in Angular 4 with Hammerjs

Tags: html, angular, hammer.js

I have noticed that the directive (swipeup) does not seem to be working:
I have tried using (swipeleft) and that works:

```
<div [@myAnimation] (swipeup)="showActionBar = false" fxFlex="56px" *ngIf="showActionBar" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutAlign="start center"fxLayoutGap="8px" class="overview-actions">
```

Does anyone have a solution / work-around for this. I have looked but didn't find a solution linked to my problem.

Thank you,
J.

Comment: How do you import hammer? does (swipe) work?

Comment: When I use (swipe) it triggers when i swipe to the left and right, but not up and down

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can import the hammer config from @angular/platform-browser and override it. Swipe up and down are off by default as they can cause issues for the user when they are trying to scroll.

**app.module.ts**

```
  import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';
  import { HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';

  export class HammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
    overrides = <any>{
      'swipe': { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL }
    };
  }

  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
        useClass: HammerConfig
      }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I had to add the override decorator `override overrides = <any>{ ...`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/684) can you try this?

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(document.body);

hammertime.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
```

And according to the documentation 
"By default it adds a set of tap, doubletap, press, horizontal pan and swipe, and the multi-touch pinch and rotate recognizers. The pinch and rotate recognizers are disabled by default because they would make the element blocking, but you can enable them by calling:

```
hammertime.get('pinch').set({ enable: true });
hammertime.get('rotate').set({ enable: true });
```

Enabling vertical or all directions for the pan and swipe recognizers:

```
hammertime.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
hammertime.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL });
```

Comment: Where would I implement this?

Comment: Where do you import hammerJS? Do you have a script tag in your code?

Comment: Thank you for the input, the answer below was the solution to my problem.